# In steam I was updating a game and it reached 100% but nothing is happening and in the downloads page it says 0Gb out of 0Gb.

Tags: steam

In steam I was updating a game and it reached 100 percent but nothing is happening and in the downloads page it says 0Gb out of 0Gb. How can I fix it?

Comment: did the download finish? or does ti still say 0Gb out of 0Gb?

Comment: Restart your PC, I could bet $100 its complete :) do not force close steam via tm

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens either if the download get's stuck, or more commonly it will happen if the download hasn't finished installing. If the game has downloaded but not fully installed it will still show as "downloading" as steam installs the game files. Steam used to show disk activity for an install, and this was easily visible as while no content was being downloaded, the game was using disk activity. Just give it 10 minutes or so depending on the size and it should finish. If not, try restarting steam.